# Grant permissions to a new role via terrafrom is not working for postgresql 14 +

Tags: postgresql, terraform, amazon-rds

I require your assistance. For Postgresql 14+, granting rights to a new role using Terraform is not functional.
This code is effective with Postgresql 13:

```
resource "postgresql_role" "role" {
  name     = "role_new_role"
  password = local.readonly_password
  login    = true
  provider = postgresql
}

resource "postgresql_grant" "grant_privileges" {
  role        = postgresql_role.role.name
  database    = each.key
  schema      = "public"
  object_type = "table"
  privileges  = var.new_user_privileges
  depends_on  = [postgresql_role.role]
}
```

but starting with Postgresql 14, if it throws an error: `Error: Error granting role pg_database_owner to RDS_MASTER_USER: pq: role "pg_database_owner" cannot have explicit members`

Answer (score 0):

`pg_database_owner` is a new pre-defined role in postgres
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/predefined-roles.html

The fix was released in version 1.21.0. so updating your postgres provider to version 1.21.0 should fix the issue.
https://github.com/cyrilgdn/terraform-provider-postgresql/pull/348

```
postgresql = {
  source  = "cyrilgdn/postgresql"
  version = "1.21.0"
}
```

More info on the issue here

- https://github.com/cyrilgdn/terraform-provider-postgresql/issues/294
- https://github.com/cyrilgdn/terraform-provider-postgresql/issues/301

Comment: this doesn't work, the version is not available in the registry

│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider cyrilgdn/postgresql: no available releases match the given constraints ~> 1.20.0, 1.22.0